# Updated R on Macbook Pro M1 Max extremely slow

Tags: r, macos, performance, rstudio, apple-m1

I just updated R and R Studio to the latest versions. Before, R ran very fast on this computer but since the update it has become painfully slow. I have checked and I think I have downloaded the correct version of R.

Here are the details of my device: 2021 Macbook Pro M1 Max, 32 GB memory
New R version: 4.2.3 (2023-03-15) -- "Shortstop Beagle"
Platform: Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
RStudio version: 2023.03.0+386

Tried restarting the device, reinstalling R but it didn't solve the issue. I also checked cpu and memory usage on system monitor and the usage looks fine.

Comment: Distinguish between R and RStudio. Can you open a terminal and run R from there (just type R) to see if R itself is slow? I strongly suspect RStudio, try a [daily](https://dailies.rstudio.com/) if its better.

Comment: @jay.sf I tried installing a daily but it didn't solve the issue. I then typed R in terminal and got this [error](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6183). I tried all the solutions on that page, but I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Looks as if something tries to load. Could you type `R --vanilla`? This should start R without loading additional stuff.

Comment: @jay.sf tried that too. Same error: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgfortran.3.dylib

Comment: For clarification, meanwhile I can still run R and Rstudio normally on my computer. It's just that it runs very slowly.

Comment: So in terminal R doesn't start at all but in RStudio it does (albeit slow)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252918/discussion-between-sarab-and-jay-sf).

Comment: Did you install R from a CRAN binary or ... ?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded R 4.2.3 binary for macOS 11 from CRAN.

Comment: After trying a lot of different ways, I realized that the issue came from Rmarkdown. My code ran fast in regular R scripts but very slow on Rmarkdown. I also still am not able to run R from terminal.